# Fast Substring Search in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, substring

We have a Mongo database with about 400,000 entries, each of which have a relatively short (< 20 characters) title.  We want to be able to do fast substring searches on these titles (fast enough to be able to use the results in things like autocomplete bars).  We are also only searching for prefixes (does the title start with *substring*).  What can we do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only do prefix searches then indexing that field should be enough. Rooted regex queries use index and should be fast.

Answer (score 2):

Sergio is correct, but to be more specific, an index on that and a left-rooted prefix without the i (case-insensitivity) flag will make efficient use of the index.  This is noted in the docs in fact:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions

Don't forget to use [.explain()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain) if you want to benchmark the queries too.

Comment: Ok, we were using the case insensitive flag. Taking that out seemed to help a bit.